# <img> src won't be change using Java Script in [ View ] [ ASP.NET MVC ]

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I try to detect if `<img>` `src` not found change it with another `src` using JQUERY, I work on ASP.NET MVC project, and the `src` come from **Controller**.

This is what I try :

**HTML**

```html
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.DATA)
  {

if (item.IMG_FRMTR != null)

     {

      ViewBag.IMG = String.Format("data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(item.IMG_FRMTR));

     }

  }

   <img id="IMG" src="@ViewBag.IMG" onerror="standby()" style="width:200px;height:200px">
```

**JQUERY**

```js
    function standby() {
       
        document.getElementById('IMG').src = 'https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png';

    }
```

**Controller Action**

```
            ViewBag.DATA = PROF_model.Select(CIN);

            return View();
```

**PROF_model.Select Method**

```
    public static List<FRMTR> Select(string CIN)
    {
        var R = (from P in SCHOOL_DB_Context.Con.FRMTRs where P.CIN_FRMTR == CIN select P).ToList();

        return R;
    }
```

Please any help ?

**Note : I look for a lot solution here in Stackoverflow but no one solve my problem**

Thanks in advance <3

Comment: In what way does it fail?  Is your `standby` function ever invoked?  What specifically happens?  The intended functionality appears to work as expected in isolation: https://jsfiddle.net/uhn7zLmw/

Comment: Firstly thanks for your answer bro, When I have an src the image dispalyed without any problem, but when img hasn't src `standby ` function not executed

Comment: If the `onerror` event isn't triggered then it sounds like there's no error.  For the `<img>` element which should be triggering an error, what is the actual resulting client-side element in the browser?  What `src` value is there?  In the browser's debugging tools, in the network tab, what is the request made for that `src` and what is the server's response?

Comment: the on error event doesn't fire if the src is blank, try something like `src="@(string.IsNullOrWhitespace(ViewBag.IMG) ? "~/0.jpj" : ViewBag.IMG)"` where `0.jpg` doesn't exist

Comment: @Pete this is the result : https://imgur.com/a/BVEITjD

Comment: XDDDD aaaah I understand now damn damn XD, thank you @Pete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for [@Pete](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1790982/pete), he gaves me a great solution that is :

**Using just HTML with `Tag Helpers` like this :**

```html
<img id="PROF_IMG" src="@(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ViewBag.IMG)?"https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" : ViewBag.IMG)" style="width:200px;height:200px">
```